# MLE in a logistic regression model

Tags: regression, self-study, logistic, maximum-likelihood

Assuming that the design matrix is of full rank, in non-degenerate cases of the logistic regression model, does the maximum likelihood estimator always exists and is always unique?

It would be really helpful if someone could provide an example or a resource link.

Comment: A simple comment with a yes or no would suffice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Logistic regression model belongs to the conditional exponential family, so per [Pitman-Koopman-Darmois theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Exponential_family) log-likelihood functions for exponential families should have unique optimal value. For a specific proof of your case where the design matrix of the logistic regression is of full rank, see [reference](http://qwone.com/%7Ejason/writing/convexLR.pdf). The basic idea is to prove the log-likelihood function of LR is convex via its Hessian similar to the single variable case via second order derivative.

Comment: I am afraid I do not see the connection with the Pitman-Koopman-Darmois theorem.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks for your critique. My intuition is from above ref: *Roughly, given a set of independent identically distributed data conditioned on an unknown parameter $\theta$ , a sufficient statistic is a function whose value contains all the information needed to compute any estimate of the parameter (e.g. a maximum likelihood estimate)...  it can easily be seen that the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$  will interact with $X$  only through $T(X)$*. But by no means this is a strict proof of the connection.